# LIncoln Continental Power Steering Leak

Tags: power-steering, leak, lincoln, continental

I have a Bad power steering leak and want to replace the pump but can't get to the fitting without removing the a/c compressor to check size.

What is the flare nut fitting size for the high pressure line 3A719 coming out of the power steering pump on a 2002 Lincoln continental?

I don't want to start the job till I have the right tool.

Comment: It is shown to be a 16mm swivel flare.  So flare wrench would be a metric.

Comment: Super, thanks. Bought the metric set and it did the job